# How do you compare two Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a function defined like this:

```
renderItem() => <Text onPress={() => console.log('hi)}>Click</Text>
```

When I call this method, I'd like to assert that the returned value is correct:

```
expect(renderItem()).toEqual(<Text onPress={() => console.log('hi)}>Click</Text>)
```

Unfortunately, the assertion is failing with this error:

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected)

Expected value to equal:

    <Text onPress={[Function onPress]}>Click</Text>

Received:

    <Text onPress={[Function onPress]}>Click</Text>

Difference:

    Compared values have no visual difference.
```

How do I test this properly?